# Maven release plugin name the files with the build version

Tags: java, maven

When I am performing a maven release:perform the name of the files generated are with the build version meaning:artifactId.version .
    I need that at least the name of the war generated when doing perform will be only the artifactId name.

```
my pom is here:

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>me.tingz</groupId>
  <artifactId>dashboard</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>15-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>dashboard Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>google</id>
            <url>file:/home/ziv/Documents/dashboard/versions/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>



  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>

       <finalName>dashboard</finalName>
        <plugins>

        <!-- Release plugin Test!!!! -->
        <plugin>

            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <configuration>

                <tagBase>
                    file:/home/ziv/tag
                </tagBase>
                 <checkModificationExcludes>
            <checkModificationExclude>pom.xml</checkModificationExclude>
        </checkModificationExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <username>zivziv</username>

        </configuration>
      </plugin>

        <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

  </build>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <scm>
        <connection>xxx</connection>
        <developerConnection>xxxd</developerConnection>
      <tag>dashboard-11</tag>

  </scm>
</project>
```

Comment: A file url looks like `file:///home/...`...

Comment: Thanks. Do you know by any chance why the generated file names are always with the version?

Answer (score 2):

The Maven Release plugin does not "generate" any files. The other plugins involved in the Maven build lifecycle, e.g. the jar plugin, do generate files. So setting the "finalName" as you did should do the trick, as far as "generation" is involved.

What the Release plugin does is

- tagging the code in the SCM
- deploying the artifacts to a repository

The latter one does ALWAYS require a Maven GAV - and the V is for Version. Otherwise, the Release would not be unique. So if you want the Release plugin to deploy an artifact to a repository without a version in its name, you will fail. This is impossible by definition.

You should think about not using the Release plugin at all - after all, it's a crappy plugin. See e.g. https://axelfontaine.com/blog/final-nail.html

Consider using the wagon-maven-plugin for achieving your goal: http://www.mojohaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/

Comment: I really thank you for your answer, I realized that using maven for releases is no good.

Comment: by the way it is not so smart to give war file different name each time since the context path of the web application is based on the war name....

Comment: @zivziv77 Are you sure you are not mixing up release <-> build? A release MUST have some sort of unique identifier, and this is best being put in the artifact's name. Of course, for an assembly for web server deployment, you could remove WAR file's version information. See Maven's assembly plugin for this.

Also, you can set the context name of a web application in other ways, e.g. using META-INF/context.xml.